# Dojo Toolkit - How to continuously trigger n event on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I am a beginner with using dojo toolkit and I am trying to create an alarm where the screen blinks red continuously when a button is pressed and only stop when the button is pressed again. I have been able to change the background color once but I dont know how to make it continuously trigger between being red or no background color.

here is my html file with the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="alarm.css" />
        <!-- load Dojo -->
        <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
        <script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
        <script> require(['myModule.js']); </script>

        <title>Alarm test</title>

    </head>

    <body class="claro">
        <h1 id="greeting">Alarm test</h1>

    <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="tableContainer">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="col1">Company</th>
                <th field="col2">Contact</th>
                <th field="col3">Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <button id="progButtonNode" type="button"></button>        
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my button on() event handler for changing the background once:

```
require(["dojo/dom-style", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(style, dom, on){
  on(dom.byId("progButtonNode"), "click", function(){      
      style.set("tableContainer", {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    });
  });
});
```

And here is my table's css. I have another question regarding this; how can I override a css using code? Because when I change the background color it only applies on the rows which does not already have a background color set like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRDGt.jpg

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here:

```
function(style, dom, on){
  on(dom.byId("progButtonNode"), "click", function(){      
      style.set("tableContainer", {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    });
  });
});
```

Could try this instead:

```
function(style, dom, on){
  on(dom.byId("progButtonNode"), "click", function(){      
      class.set("tableContainer", {
      "blink" // or however you add a class in dojo, not sure 
    });
  });
});
```

And your `css` would look like this

```
.blink {
    animation:blink 700ms infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
    from { background-color: white; }
    to { background-color: red; }
};
```

In dojo, there should be an easy to `toggle` a class similar to jQuery. If not, just add a conditional to check if the class is there. If it is, remove the class `blink` and the effect will go away.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way of doing this would be

```
/*js*/
require(["dojo/dom-style", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(style, dom, on, domClass) {
    var blink;
    on(dom.byId("progButtonNode"), "click", function() {      
        if(blink) {
            clearInterval(blink);
            blink = null;
        } else {
            blink = setInterval(function() {
                domClass.toggle("tableContainer", "background");
            }, 1000); // 1 second
        }
    });
});
```

And add this class to your css file

```
/*css*/
.background {
    background-color: red;
}
```